# S3 Storage requirements for Rundeck

Tags: rundeck

How much storage does Rundeck need in S3 for log storage for say 100 jobs, 100 executions a day?
There is no information in the docs about minimum storage requirements, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple experiment. If one execution (on my example it's a [simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xizd.jpg) "hello world!" print) takes 2.4 kB then 2.4 kB x 100 = 240 kB (100 executions), and  240 kB x 100 = 24.000 kB = 24 MB per day (100 executions of 100 jobs). Of course, that depends on your job outputs, my example is just a "hello world!" string printed.

Anyway, this is not a big deal for the Amazon [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/) service (check "How much data can I store in Amazon S3?" section).